# How to remove contents from CALayer?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `CALayer` with some image contents. When a button touched, I want to remove the contents from the layer, and I use this code:

```
[m_aCellLayer setContents:nil]
```

but I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception when executing above line. Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the obvious stuff: is m_aCellLayer valid when you make this call, or has it been deallocated? Did you try NSLog()ing it just before you make the call?